# remove comma from last element in array

Tags: php

```
<?php
one = "A";
$two = "B";
$three = "C";
$four = "D";
$message = "";

$hello = array();
$hello['one'] = $one;
$hello['two'] = $two;
$hello['three'] = $three;
$hello['four'] = $four;

foreach ($hello as $value){
    if (empty($value)){
        $message .= $value;
    }   else
    $message .= $value.",";
}
echo $message;
?>
```

the above code gives the output as:
A,B,C,D,
please give me a way to to remove the last comma even if i remove any other value.
Thank you

Comment: the first one is obviously $one

Comment: Its the else statement....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rtrim()` and put `,` as one of the characters that need to be trimmed.

```
$message = rtrim($message, ',');
echo $message;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't add the comma you dont want to have. Can be nicely done with `implode()`

```
<?php
$one = "A";
$two = "B";
$three = "C";
$four = "D";
$message = "";

$hello = array();
$hello['one'] = $one;
$hello['two'] = $two;
$hello['three'] = $three;
$hello['four'] = $four;

$message = implode(',', $hello);
echo $message;
```

`implode()` concatenates all values of the given array and put the first argument (called "glue") in between all values.

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php for further explanation and examples.

If you have empty values in your data you may want to do some pre processing to only `implode()` the parts with actual content:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($hello as $value){
    if (!empty($value)){
      $output[] = $value;
    }
}
$message = implode(',', $output);
echo $message;
```

Comment: thanx, the link helped a lot :)

Comment: but the problem with using implode is that if i omit any value it just shows wmpty space between two commas, which i don't want!

Comment: yes thankyou this helps...ok now can you write a program for me that gives out the exact output, but only using if-else statements.

Comment: What does "but only using if-else statements"? And thank you for offering me the unique opportunity to "write a program for me that gives out the exact output".

Comment: your welcome, what i mean is that instead of using foreach i just want to use if-else statements and not use any loop,

Comment: You did not even mention this in your original question. If you have a close look at all the provided answers you are probably to do this on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$message = rtrim($message, ',');`.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
foreach ($hello as $key => $value){
    if (key($hello) !== 0) {
        $message .= ",";
    }
    $message .= $value;
}
```